# MVC3 EF4 duplicates foreign key object on save

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, code-first

I'm using MVC3 with EF4 code-first. I have the following model:

```
public class Order {

    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public float Price { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int PayMethodId { get; set; }
    public PayMethod PayMethod { get; set; }

    public int? SpecificEventId { get; set; }
    public SpecificEvent SpecificEvent { get; set; }

    public int? SeasonalTicketId { get; set; }
    public SeasonalTicket SeasonalTicket { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to save an Order object with `specificEventId = 2` and `specificEvent = X`, a new `SpecificEvent` object is created in the DB, even though there's already a specific event X with ID 2 in the DB. When i try with `specificEventId = 2` and `specificEvent = null` I get a data validation error.

**What am I doing wrong?** I want `SpecificEvent` and `SeasonalTicket` to be nullable, and I don't want EF4 to create a new instance of these objects in the DB whenever I save 'Order'.

**Update**

This is my code for saving `Order` in the DB:

```
public void SaveOrder(Order order)
{
    Order fromDb = null;

    // If editing an existing object.
    if ((fromDb = GetOrder(order.ID)) != null)
    {
        db = new TicketsDbContext();
        db.Entry(order).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    // If adding a new object.
    else
    {
        db.orders.Add(order);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

When I save, I do reach the `else` clause.

Comment: This is most common question about EF so I wonder what did you search for before you asked the question?

Comment: @Ladislav : I searched for "ef\mvc optional foreign key", "ef\mvc object duplicates on save" etc... I found some examples that are close to my case, but it still didn't work for me. Maybe I missed something (though I did check and double check myself) or maybe I searched for the wrong thing. I tried to debug this bug for several hours now (I'm kind of an EF noob :). If you think that I'm missing something obvious or have any suggestions for other things I can look for, I'd be more than happy to hear :)

Comment: You should add your code for saving entity to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real question is, where did you get the instance of X from?  It appears as though EF has no knowledge of this instance.  You either need to fetch the already existing SpecificEvent through EF and use the proxy it returns to set your navigation property, or else tell EF to "attach" X, so that it knows what your intent is.  As far as EF knows, it appears, you are trying to send it a new instance with a conflicting Id, so it is properly issuing the error.

Comment: I got it from the DB using EF, and sure enough when I view the object in debug mode, it seems that the ID is correct (matches both the ID in Order and the ID in the DB). I did get it in a previous request from the server and saved it in the session, I made the actual save attempt only on a following request. To my understanding it's not a problem.

Comment: In that case, it is from a different context, the one from the prior request is probably long gone.  You'll need to attach it to the new context.